# Why is my HttpResponseExceptionFilter not working with synchronized action on NET.Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've implemented a HttpResponseExceptionFilter in Asp.Net Core Web Api to handle errors and format them in a fixed format json string.Here is my code:

```
public class HttpResponseExceptionFilter : IAsyncExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly ILogger<HttpResponseExceptionFilter> _logger;

    public HttpResponseExceptionFilter(ILogger<HttpResponseExceptionFilter> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception == null)
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        switch (context.Exception)
        {
            case BadHttpRequestException ex:
                context.Result = new JsonResult(new BaseResponse<object?>()
                {
                    StatusCode = ex.StatusCode,
                    Message = ex.Message,
                    Data = null
                })
                {
                    StatusCode = ex.StatusCode
                };
                break;
            default:
                _logger.LogError(context.Exception, "error");
                context.Result = new JsonResult(new BaseResponse<object?>()
                {
                    StatusCode = 500,
                    Message = context.Exception.Message,
                    Data = null
                })
                {
                    StatusCode = 500
                };
                break;
        }
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and add it in `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<HttpResponseExceptionFilter>();
});
```

then I throw an exception in controller action(for example):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserRegisterRequest registerRequest)
{
    throw new BadHttpRequestException("error details", 500);
    User user = await _userService.Register(registerRequest);
    return JsonResult(user);
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(string account, string password)
{
    throw new BadHttpRequestException("error details", 500);
    string token = _userService.Login(account, password);
    return JsonResult(new LoginResponse() { Token = token });
}
```

then, it will work with Register method but doesn't work with Login method and if I convert Login method into `public async Task<IActionResult>  Login(string account, string password)` it works.
So are there reasons to explain this?And how can I make it work with synchronized action?
By the way I've tried using UseExceptionHandler and it performs as the same way.